# How do I hold onto a factory function in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to hold a function that will return new instances of a type implementing a particular interface in a struct. Here's a stripped down example:

```
package main

type Adder interface {
    Add(Adder)
    Val() int
}

type NewAdder func() Adder

type number int

type NewHolder struct {
    newFunc NewAdder
}

func (me *number)Add(it Adder) {
    *me += number(it.Val())
}

func (me *number)Val() int {
    return int(*me)
}

func newAdder() *number {
    return (*number)(new(int))
}

func main() {
    var holder NewHolder
    holder.newFunc = NewAdder(newAdder)
}
```

When I try to compile it, it says `cannot convert newAdder (type func() *number) to type NewAdder`. So what's the go-like way to accomplish my goal?

Here's a Python example of what I'm trying to do, just for reference:

```
class NewStuffMaker(object):
    def __init__(self, new):
        self.new = new

def make_new():
    return []
obj = NewStuffMaker(make_new)
new_lst = obj.new()
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to hold a bunch of these functions (or structs containing the functions and some other data) in a slice. Is that an unreasonable thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

type Adder interface {
    Add(Adder)
    Val() int
}

type FuncAdder func() Adder

type Holder struct {
    FuncAdder
    SomeOtherData string
}

type number int

func (n *number) Add(a Adder) {
    *n += number(a.Val())
}

func (n *number) Val() int {
    return int(*n)
}

func NumberAdder() Adder {
    return Adder(new(number))
}

func main() {
    var holders []Holder
    var holder Holder
    holder.FuncAdder = NumberAdder
    holder.SomeOtherData = "SomeOtherData"
    holders = append(holders, holder)
}
```

Comment: For future people, if anyone else has this problem, the key bit is that the function is declared as returning the interface, not the type that implements the interface.